# python script to create JMS connection factory & update JMS adapter using WLST

Tags: python, jms, soa, wlst

Anyone has a python script to create JMS connection factory & update JMS adapter to redeploy that I can use as a sample. Please help.

Comment: Several Oracle docs says there is a sample configJMSSystemResource.py but can not find this file. Anyone have this that they can share?

Answer (score 1):

That particular script is in ORACLE_HOME\wlserver_10.3\samples\server\examples\src\examples\wlst\online

```
"""
This script starts an edit session, creates two different JMS Servers, 
targets the jms servers to the server WLST is connected to and creates
jms topics, jms queues and jms templates in a JMS System module. The 
jms queues and topics are targeted using sub-deployments. 
"""

import sys
from java.lang import System


print "Starting the script ..."
connect('weblogic','welcome1','t3://localhost:7001')
edit()
startEdit()

servermb=getMBean("Servers/examplesServer")
if servermb is None:
    print 'Value is Null'

else:
    jmsserver1mb = create('MyJMSServer1','JMSServer')
    jmsserver1mb.addTarget(servermb)
    jmsserver2mb = create('MyJMSServer2','JMSServer')
    jmsserver2mb.addTarget(servermb)

    jmsMySystemResource = create("myJmsSystemResource","JMSSystemResource")
    jmsMySystemResource.addTarget(servermb)

    subDep1mb = jmsMySystemResource.createSubDeployment('DeployToJMSServer1')
    subDep1mb.addTarget(jmsserver1mb)
    subDep2mb = jmsMySystemResource.createSubDeployment('DeployToJMSServer2')
    subDep2mb.addTarget(jmsserver2mb)

    theJMSResource = jmsMySystemResource.getJMSResource()

    connfact1 = theJMSResource.createConnectionFactory('MyCF1')
    connfact1.setJNDIName('jms.MyCF1')
    connfact1.setSubDeploymentName('DeployToJMSServer1')
    connfact2 = theJMSResource.createConnectionFactory('MyCF2')
    connfact2.setJNDIName('jms.MyCF2')
    connfact2.setSubDeploymentName('DeployToJMSServer2')

    print "Creating MyQueue1..."
    jmsqueue1 = theJMSResource.createQueue('MyQueue1')
    jmsqueue1.setJNDIName('jms.MyJMSQueue1')
    jmsqueue1.setSubDeploymentName('DeployToJMSServer1')

    print "Creating MyQueue2..."
    jmsqueue2 = theJMSResource.createQueue('MyQueue2')
    jmsqueue2.setJNDIName('jms.MyJMSQueue2')
    jmsqueue2.setSubDeploymentName('DeployToJMSServer2')

    print "Creating MyTopic1..."
    jmstopic1 = theJMSResource.createTopic("MyTopic1")
    jmstopic1.setJNDIName('jms.MyJMSTopic1')
    jmstopic1.setSubDeploymentName('DeployToJMSServer1')

    print "Creating MyTopic2..."
    jmstopic2 = theJMSResource.createTopic("MyTopic2")
    jmstopic2.setJNDIName('jms.MyJMSTopic2')
    jmstopic2.setSubDeploymentName('DeployToJMSServer2')

    print "Creating MyJMSTemplate..."
    jmstemplate = theJMSResource.createTemplate('MyJMSTemplate')
    jmstemplate.setMaximumMessageSize(20)    

try:
    save()
    activate(block="true")
    print "script returns SUCCESS"   
except:
    print "Error while trying to save and/or activate!!!"
    dumpStack()
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the path to the file & the file contents. It really helped.